# How can I create an exact clone / copy of a row in parse class in a new class i.e. archive a row

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a parse app and im trying to 'archive' old rows of data from a class called "Data" to another class called "DataArchive"

I'm doing this using a cloud scheduled job which is all working great as a purge job i.e. im selecting my rows for a set criteria and then i'm calling .destroy()  in my .each logic  e.g.

```
mainQuery.each(function(dataRow) {
    counter += 1;
    _log(dataRow.get("type") + " " + dataRow.id)
    //DataArchive = dataRow.clone()
    return dataRow.destroy();

}).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success(counter + " Games archived successfully.");
    _log(counter + " Games archived successfully.");
}, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
});
```

I thought is was probably not best to just delete the rows so now im trying to 'move' the row from Data to DataArchive.

I saw the .clone()  method which I thought would work but it just creates a clone within the same class i.e. Data in my case.

Does anybody have any suggestions (without specifying each column one by one) on how this can be achieved?

Thanks